Type narrowing doesn't work for (almost) discriminated union
Given the following type definition:
type A = { a: string } | { a?: undefined; b: string }

Which basically means, if you provide a, that's all you should provide. If you do not provide a, or you provide a but it's undefined, you have to also provide b
I'm expecting to be able to access b if a is undefined per the code below:
let t = true
// The purpose in this line of code is to confuse the compiler such that it won't narrow the definition right in this line of code.
const z: A = t ? { a: 'a' } : { b: 'b' }

if (z.a) {
  console.log(z.a)
} else {
  console.log(z.b)
}

What i'm getting is the following error message::
Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'.
  Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'

Here a link to ts playground with the relevant code.
I'm expecting a solution that is typesafe. i.e. no testing for property existence using unsafe string such as hasOwnProperty('b') and no type assersions.
Is that possible?


What i'm getting is the following error message::
Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'.
  Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'


The reason you're getting that error message is that it's possible to get in the else block and still have a string on the z.a property. This will happen if z.a is an empty string "". So in fact the type hasn't been narrowed at all in the else case.
If you switch it to this it will work:
if (typeof z.a === 'string') {
  console.log(z.a)
} else {
  console.log(z.b)
}

Playground link

Your check should be more explicit:
if (z.a !== undefined) {
  console.log(z.a)
} else {
  console.log(z.b)   // compiles
}

The reason your code doesn't work is that z.a could be '', which is a string, but falsy, which would cause the else branch be taken for something which doesn't have a z.b ...
